# Python global keyword weird behaviour

Tags: python, global

```
def a():
    g=1
    def b():
        global g
        g=2
        def c():
            global g
            g=3
        c()
        print("c", g) #3
    b()
    print("b", g) #1 
a()
print("a", g) #3
```

The output is

```
c 3
b 1
a 3
```

I can't understand why the value of `g` is `1` inside `a()` but `3` outside `a()`

If value of `g` is `3` in two places:

1. after calling `c()`
2. outside `a()`.

Why is it `1` inside `a()`?

Comment: Because you don't have `global g` inside `a`? This is a perfect example why global variables should be avoided. If it's hard to debug across a 14 lines code, imagine doing this across an entire code base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `g=1` in `a()` it creates a new ***local*** variable to that function. When you do `global g` in `b()` and `c()` it makes `g` refer to the global variable (which doesn't yet exist when running `b`). So `c`, `b` and the global scope all refer to the same `g` (which is 3 after running `c`) while `a` refers to its local `g` which never changed and is still 1.

Changing `global` to `nonlocal` will make both prints of `c` and `b` to print 3, but now will make a `NameError` for the last print as there is no `g` in the global scope.

Alternatively, adding `global g` to the start of `a`, will have all three prints print 3.